# Why cannot my app create fitness.runs for test users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

My web app can successfully create fitness.runs for myself and friends, but not for test users (created in the Test Users view of the Roles tab of the App's Dashboard). So I have a problem getting the app approved in the review, required for explicit sharing.
The app makes the following HTTP request to create (line breaks in content for readability):

```
POST /me/fitness.runs HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

course=https%3A%2F%2Fbroker-web.appspot.com%2Fpub%2Fcourse%2FagxzfmJyb2tlci13ZWJyLAsSDERQYXJ0aWNpcGFudBiAgICA_fCfCgwLEgZEU3BsaXQYgICAgICAgAoM
&start_time=2014-04-30T13%3A43%3A46
&expires_in=86400
&object=%7B%22app_id%22%3A%22255653361131262%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Demo+410m%22%7D
&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The successful response contains the action id (for myself and friends), and for test users the following error message is returned:

```
HTTP 500 OK

{error={message=An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later., type=OAuthException, code=2}}
```

The crawler was successful visiting the object:

```
89.236.16.14 - - [30/Apr/2014:06:45:13 -0700] "GET /pub/course/agxzfmJyb2tlci13ZWJyLAsSDERQYXJ0aWNpcGFudBiAgICA_fCfCgwLEgZEU3BsaXQYgICAgICAgAoM HTTP/1.1" 200 6211 -
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36" 
"broker-web.appspot.com" ms=135 cpu_ms=41 cpm_usd=0.000694 app_engine_release=1.9.4 instance=00c61b117ce48a0349d573d3cd16b02587ffe00b
```

Comment: Doing a GET on your object URL is failing: https://broker-web.appspot.com/pub/course/agxzfmJyb2tlci13ZWJyLAsSDERQYXJ0aWNpcGFudBiAgICA_fCfCgwLEgZEU3BsaXQYgICAgICAgAoM

Also can you post your FB App ID?

Finally, can you confirm what you mean by Test User? Do you mean users you created in the Test Users view of the Roles tab of your App's Dashboard?

Comment: The GET may have failed because of a temporary out-of-quota.

Comment: And confirming the Test User.

Answer (score 0):

My app was using the wrong FB app ID when creating the action. That is an issue only for Test Users, as they exist for the correct FB App only.